Why does moment of inertia stop at 1/2 as solidness of a cylinder increases?
So I have two things about moment of inertia:
The I for a hoop is $I=MR^2$ and
the I for a solid disk is $I=\frac{1}{2}MR^2$
I've noticed that as "solidness" goes up from 0% (completely unsolid, hoop) to 100% (solid disk) the moment of inertia lowers until it's exactly 1/2 of the hoop (when it's solid).
Using the equation for a cylinder bound by $R_1$ (inner radius) and $R_2$ (outer radius) of $$I=\frac{1}{2}M(R_1^2+R_2^2)$$
we can think of "solidness" as the inverse percentage $R_1$ is of $R_2$.
I plotted this on a graph taking $R_1$ as the x-axis and moment of inertia I as the y-axis (and assumed $R_2=1$ and $M=1$):

The question I have is: why does moment of inertia stop at 1/2 as the disk becomes 100% solid? Is this something inherent to the geometry of circles where $I=\frac{1}{2}$ if there's a mass of 1 kg distributed equally over a circle of radius 1m? Why is it specifically $I=\frac{1}{2}$?
Also, why is the graph parabolic from 1/2? I know it's parabolic because it's based on the $I=\frac{1}{2}M(R_1^2+R_2^2)$ parabolic equation but intuitively why does I go up parabolically?

The reason that the moment of inertia gets smaller as the annulus gets less like a hoop and more like a disc is that more of the mass is closer to the axis of rotation.  You can make the moment of inertia even smaller if you make the density of the disc non-uniform.  For example, the moment of inertia for a solid sphere with uniform density is $\frac25 mr^2 = 0.4 mr^2$.  But if you care about the moment of inertia of the Earth, you have to account for the Earth's differentiation, where most of the dense iron sank out of the mantle into the core; the Earth's actual moment of inertia is closer to $0.33 mr^2$.
If you want to know why the prefactor for a solid disc is one-half, rather than two-thirds for a hollow sphere or two-fifths for a solid ball or one-third for a rod around the end or one-twelfth for a rod about its middle, you have to do calculus.  Most people do those integrals by hand at most once, while they're taking their introductory course, and then look at the cheat sheet for the rest of their careers.
Let's do the disc.

The moment of inertia for a disc is the sum of the moments of inertia for all the little rings that make up the disc.  If the disc is continuous, you use an integral instead of a sum.  If the disc is thick, you can call it a cylinder.
I like to write
$$
I = \int r_\perp^2 \mathrm dm
$$
to emphasize that it's all of the little bits of mass that we're adding up.  Here $r_\perp$ is the distance from the axis of rotation; that way the expression is still correct if we move on to some complicated three-dimensional shape.  But I'll drop the ${}_\perp$ subscript for now, because we don't need it for a ring or a disc, and it's annoying to type.
Whenever I teach this, I have some students who are totally okay with $\int \mathrm dx = x$ if $x$ is some positional variable, but get a sinking feeling in their stomach when I write $\int \mathrm dm = m$ for a less obviously positional variable like a mass.  If that's you … you'll be okay.
If all of the mass is at the same radius, like a single particle or a hoop, the integral is trivial: $$I = \int r^2\mathrm dm = r^2 \int \mathrm dm = r^2 m.$$
For an annulus — that is, a disc with inner and outer radii $r_{1,2}$ — we split the mass up into rings with constant radius $r$.  Each little ring has some circumference $2\pi r$, and some thickness $\mathrm dr$, and mass
$$
\mathrm dm = \rho \cdot 2\pi r\,\mathrm  dr.
$$
We find the density by doing the integral for just the mass:
\begin{align}
m &= \int \mathrm dm \\&= \int_{r_1}^{r_2} \rho\cdot 2\pi r\,\mathrm dr
\\
m &= 2\pi\rho \cdot \frac12\left(
r_2^2 - r_1^2
\right) \tag 1
\\
\frac{m}{
\pi r_2^2 - \pi r_1^2
} &=\rho \tag 2
\end{align}
The relation (2) is just the standard equation for an area density.  The area of the annulus is the area of the outer circle minus the area of the inner circle, $\pi r_2^2 - \pi r_1^2$.
Now let's do the same process for the moment of inertia:
\begin{align}
I = \int r^2\mathrm dm &= \int_{r_1}^{r_2} r^2\cdot\rho\cdot 2\pi r\,\mathrm dr
\\
&= 2\pi\rho\int_{r_1}^{r_2} r^3\mathrm dr \tag 3
\\ 
&= 2\pi\rho \cdot \frac14\left(r_2^4 - r_1^4\right)
\\
&= \left[2\pi\rho \cdot \frac12\left(r_2^2 - r_1^2\right)\right]\frac12\left(r_2^2 + r_1^2\right)
\\ &= m \cdot \frac12\left(r_2^2 + r_1^2\right) \tag 4
\end{align}
There are two dirty tricks here that beginning students don't like.  One trick is the difference-of-squares rule, $a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$; the other is finding the expression (1) for the overall mass in the moment of inertia integral, for which there are several tedious methods. I usually remember which tedious method I hate the least about a week after I've taught that class.

So if your question is "why one-half," the answer really is this page of calculus.
If you do a hollow-to-solid sphere, I think you get a -fifth in the denominator because you have a volume density instead of an area density. That change means the step equivalent to (3) has $\int r^4 \mathrm dr$ instead of $\int r^3\mathrm dr$.

The moment of inertia comes from the definition of angular momentum for a particle $\vec L = \vec r \times \vec p$. In the case of a disk, $\vec r$ is always perpendicular to $\vec p$ for any point, so we can say for the modulus of the vectors: $$L = rp = rdmv = dmr\omega r = dmr^2\omega$$ for any point, where $dm$ is the infinitesimal mass around the point.
The angular momentum of the disk is the integral along all its points:
$$L = \int (dm)r^2\omega$$
The angular velocity is the same for any point in a rigid body, so it can be taken out of the integral.
$$L = \omega\int (dm)r^2$$
The integral is called momentum of inertia $I$. If $\rho$ is the surface density of the disk, and constant, it can also be taken out of the integral:
$$I = \rho\int_S r^2dS = \rho\int_r\int_{\theta} r^2rd\theta dr$$
The integral in $\theta$ is $2\pi$:
$$I = \rho 2\pi\int_r r^3dr = \frac {1}{2}\rho\pi r^4|_{r1}^{r2} = \frac {1}{2}\rho\pi (r_2^4 - r_1^4)$$
Here can be seen the origin of the term $\frac{1}{2}$.
For a massive disk ($r_1=0$ and $r_2=R$):
$$I = \frac {1}{2}\rho\pi R^4 = \frac {1}{2}\rho\pi R^2R^2 = \frac {1}{2}MR^2$$
When $r_1$ is very close to $r_2$, they can be approximated by $R$ in the sum:
$$(r_2^4 - r_1^4) = (r_2^2 + r_1^2)(r_2^2 - r_1^2) = 2R^2(r_2^2 - r_1^2)$$
So,
$$I = \frac {1}{2}\rho\pi 2R^2(r_2^2 - r_1^2) = \rho\pi (r_2^2 - r_1^2)R^2 = MR^2$$
When $r_1$ is not so close to $r_2$ and is greater than zero, we are between these extremes values.

Minor comment: consider \ \mathrm dm\  to set the differential term apart from its neighbors.

Suppose you have all the mass $M$ concentrated in a ring of radius $R_2$. Then $I = MR_2^2$.
Now spread the mass out between $R_1$ and $R_2$. $I$ is less because some of the mass is closer to the center.
Set $R_1 = 0$. $I$ drops to half its previous value.

You could probably motivate it with an exact calculation, that's depending on OPs familiarity using integration.
